# DevExpress - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nodeName')

Tags: javascript, jquery, devexpress, devextreme

I was getting this error with my complex code, so I simplified it below. The Data Grid gets created and displays. Also, clicking a row displays the alert. However the immediate alert dialog gives this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nodeName')"

Is there something I need to do before trying to display the alert right when the page loads? I want to avoid the standard JS alert() function.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myGrid").dxDataGrid({
        dataSource: [{
            "Name": "John",
            "Age": 25
        },{
            "Name": "George",
            "Age": 27
        },{
            "Name": "Betty",
            "Age": 30
        }],
        onRowClick(e) {
            DevExpress.ui.dialog.alert("Testing", "Confirm");
        }
    });
    DevExpress.ui.dialog.alert("Testing", "Confirm");
});
```

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- DevExtreme theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/22.1.5/css/dx.light.css">

<!-- DevExtreme library -->
<script src="https://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/22.1.5/js/dx.all.js"></script>

<div id="myGrid"></div>
```

Comment: Looks like the library needs to wait for load not document ready

Comment: I put in the following code, but now I get the error that the DevExpress bundle is already loaded. Which it is, but it's being loaded in a global header file. How do I keep the following code but suppress the error? $.getScript('https://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/22.1.5/js/dx.all.js')
    .done(function(script, textStatus) {
     DevExpress.ui.dialog.alert("Testing", "Confirm");
    })
    .fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception) {
     console.log('Failed to load DevExtreme library');
    });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you saw is likely due to a compatibility issue between the version of **jQuery** used by **DevExtreme** and the version of **jQuery(1.11.3)** used in your project.

##### So I tried with updated `jQuery.v3.6.0` and it works.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#myGrid").dxDataGrid({
    dataSource: [
      {
        Name: "John",
        Age: 25,
      },
      {
        Name: "George",
        Age: 27,
      },
      {
        Name: "Betty",
        Age: 30,
      },
    ],
    onRowClick(e) {
      DevExpress.ui.dialog.alert("Testing", "Confirm");
    },
  });
  DevExpress.ui.dialog.alert("Testing", "Confirm");
});
```

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<!-- DevExtreme theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/22.1.5/css/dx.light.css" />

<!-- DevExtreme library -->
<script src="https://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/22.1.5/js/dx.all.js"></script>

<div id="myGrid"></div>
```

Comment: Perfect. I'll have to let my organization know that jQuery is severely out of date and needs to be updated. Thank you.